# What kind of Exercise can be done amidst in office hours?

Tags: strength, back-pain

I am a typical office goer who sits around `9 - 10 hours` in front of my `system`. There are no possibilities here to do any ground exercises.

Usually I play `badminton` after office hours for atleast an hour.

> Is that enough?
>
> Are there any simple tricks or workouts like stretching(`during my office hours`) which could be really get me through out the day?

Needed a reply which could help in making me active all time.

**EDIT:** [Ensuring Physical Health while sat idle most of the day](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/31099/ensuring-physical-health-while-sat-idle-most-of-the-day?noredirect=1&lq=1) Question is different and same as the answer. Please provide a good solution according to my criteria.